# Learning Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am new to Oracle. I have been using SQL-Server for the past 3 yrs. I want to learn basic database queries in Oracle, creating functions, stored procedures and operations like database restore, backup and attach.

Do I need to install Oracle client or server? Is Oracle 10g a good choice? Any tutorial or link for Oracle will be of great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Did [the product pages at oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/overview/index.html?origref=http://www.oracle.com/index.html) not provide any useful information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the fine materials available at oracle site:
http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/homepage
Start with the 2-day document.

Why use 10g? 11g is there for almost 5 years.

Comment: Oracle 12c is out this autumn!

Comment: 2013? ;-) Can't find it for download on technet...

Comment: 12c is not available yet but it will be soon. I was just agreeing with you that it was a bad idea to learn 10g.

Comment: For some reason my eyes read Autumn and my brain registered Spring. I should use google translate. ;-p

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle documentation is online. Find it [here](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/homepage/).

The 11g documentation has some good overview stuff.  Everybody ought to read the [Concepts Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/toc.htm). However the impatient should jump straight to either the [2 Day DBA Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/toc.htm) or the [2 Day Developers Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10766/toc.htm).

I suggest you to learn 11g unless you have a sound business reason to learn a more historical version.  You can download it from [Oracle Technet](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win32soft-098987.html). The OTN license allows us to install Oracle software for the purpose of self-learning. So you can install an Enterprise Edition on your laptop to teach yourself Oracle but you can't use it to build a system for a client.